# How do I decide if this desktop will be better than my laptop in terms of overall performance?

Tags: laptop, desktop

I don't know much in detail about how CPUs performance matters and how i5 and i7 should be compared in this scenario. I just know the basic truth that i7 can handle multiple tasks. That's what I've heard. i7 is better than i5.

I've also heard from some people that desktops are often faster than laptops because it has "bigger" parts.

I've a laptop`[1]`. Everything is good but Graphics Card is very old. I mainly do design work and some video editing and a bit 3D modelling in Blender for personal work (Nothing advanced).

My current laptop performs okay for these things. Especially Graphic Design with Adobe Software. There's no issue in designing. Videos and 3D is also okay for my needs.

But I want to play some games like GTA5, Call of Duty from 2019/2020, CSGO etc. on my weekends or whenever I'm free. I'm not an addict to games though. For these, my laptop performs very bad. It runs only in lowest resolution and settings.

I want to play games in almost full performance settings. 1920 resolution is not necessary, 1368 would also be good, but I need a significant better performance. And for this, I find NVIDIA 1660 pretty good, considering my budget.

So I found this`[2]` desktop. It has everything good, I can add 8GB more RAM, but the processor is i5. And my laptop is i7. That's only thing that is stopping me to buy this desktop.

I'm not really sure how much is it going to affect my design and video performance. I'm sure games will be better without any doubt on desktop. But not sure if Adobe software and video editing and basic 3D modeling would be a little slower than my laptop.

I spend most of my time in browsing Internet and static graphic designing and basic video editing. Games is just a hobby. But I sure want to play games. **But I don't want to buy this desktop (even thought I know it plays games very well) at the cost of losing my current laptop's performance, especially i7.**

I also feel that now that i9 is released, i5 is too old. So with my i7 laptop, I'm still better/ahead.

**So how do I decide if this i5 desktop would be a better option overall or a bad choice?**

`[1]`
Device: Dell Inspiron 7570
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz
RAM: 16 GB
GPU: 940MX
256 GB SSD, 1 TB Hard drive, Windows 10

`[2]`
Desktop:

ASUS Core i5 (9400F) (8 GB RAM/NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Graphics/1 TB Hard Disk/512 GB SSD Capacity/Windows 10 (64-bit)/6 GB Graphics Memory) Gaming Tower  (ROG Strix GL10CS-IN080T)

Answer (score 1):

The desktop's CPU will run circles around that laptop's. This is because the i5-9400f has two more cores than the laptop and runs at nearly double the refresh rate of the laptops. The 'I' series is basically a marketing thing and only roughly estimates performance in the same generation, not cross generations. It's confusing, I know. I would deeply recommend that desktop as it is faster in pretty much every key area and don't need to worry about the CPU is slower than your laptop's.

Comment: One more thing, as you can see from CPU name, the i5-9400F don't have inbuilt GPU. That isn't much needed because i will be having a better nvidia gpu anyway? or will i miss something because of lack of intel gpu?

Comment: @Vikas You'll miss a tiny of bit of efficiency in low GPU load situations, but for a desktop, nobody usually cares about that.
The desktop CPU will be superior in *all* workloads: https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-8550U-vs-Intel-Core-i5-9400F/m320742vs4051

Comment: @towe yeah just checked looks like i5 is better than this laptop i7. But I was just curious about specifically about GPU. If you know, in laptops, you have settings to set your preferred GPU for different apps. Smaller apps have Intel GPU as default and heavy apps and games have Nvidia GPU.

But if I buy this desktop, I won't have inbuilt GPU. So those each and every app, even smaller apps, would use NVIDIA GPU. So would it degrade any overall performance of those apps or it would still work fine just like Intel GPU?

Comment: @Vikas Those apps would work just fine; usually much better than with the integrated GPU, but you'll use a bit more power doing so.